# How to make 2 while loops work at the same time in python turtle

Tags: python, while-loop, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want to make the two blocks move, but when the first block moved to the middle, it stoped. Then the second one start moving when the first block is in (0,0). Is it possible to let the second block and first block both move but the first one start first?

Here is the code:

```
from turtle import *
import time
import random

screen=Screen()
screen.setup(800,400)
x=0
blockx=500
blockx2=500
t1=Turtle(shape="square")
t1.speed(0)
speed(0)
t2 = Turtle ( shape="square" )
t2.speed ( 0 )
t2.up ( )
t2.goto ( blockx2 , -100 )
t2.down ( )
up ( )
goto (500, -110)
down ( )
goto(-500,-110)

while True:
    t1.up()
    t1.goto(blockx,-100)
    t1.down()
    blockx-=10
    if blockx==-500:
        t1.up ( )
        blockx+=1000
        t1.goto ( blockx , -100 )
        t1.down ( )
    if blockx==0:
        t2.up ( )
        t2.goto(blockx2,-100)
        t2.down()
        t2.shape("square")
        blockx2-=10
        if blockx2==-500:
            t2.up ( )
            blockx2+=1000
            t2.goto ( blockx , -100 )
            t2.down ( )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `ontimer()` events to control your blocks more independently:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 400
CURSOR_SIZE = 20
BASELINE = -CURSOR_SIZE/2

def move_block(block):
    block.x -= CURSOR_SIZE/2
    block.setx(block.x)

    if block.x <= CURSOR_SIZE/2 - WIDTH/2:
        block.x += WIDTH + CURSOR_SIZE
        block.setx(block.x)

    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(lambda: move_block(block), 30)  # delay in milliseconds

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen.tracer(False)

marker = Turtle()
marker.hideturtle()
marker.penup()
marker.goto(WIDTH/2, BASELINE)
marker.pendown()
marker.goto(-WIDTH/2, BASELINE)

block_1 = Turtle(shape="square")
block_1.penup()
block_1.color('red')
block_1.x = WIDTH/2 + CURSOR_SIZE  # user defined property
block_1.setx(block_1.x)

block_2 = block_1.clone()
block_2.color('green')
block_2.x = block_1.x + 125
block_2.setx(block_2.x)

block_3 = block_2.clone()
block_3.color('blue')
block_3.x = block_2.x + 75
block_3.setx(block_3.x)

move_block(block_1)
move_block(block_2)
move_block(block_3)

screen.mainloop()
```

One aspect to consider in your solution, or a suggested one, is how much your code has to change if you want to add one more block.

Answer (score 2):

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

from turtle import *
import time
import random

screen = Screen()
screen .setup( 800, 400 )

blockx = 500  ##  set start positions,
blockx2 = 600  ##  for both blocks

t1 = Turtle( shape='square' )
t1 .color( 'red' )
t1 .speed( 0 )
t1 .up()

##  t1 & t2 are essentially the same.
##  You can use .clone() here to copy t1's properties, & save typing those same commands again.
t2 = t1 .clone()
t2 .color( 'blue' )

while True:
    blockx -= 10  ##  nudge both positions left
    blockx2 -= 10

    t1 .goto( blockx, -100 )
    t2 .goto( blockx2, -100 )

    if blockx == -500:  ##  if either hit the left side of screen,
        blockx  = 500  ##  then set position back to right side of screen
    if blockx2 == -500:
        blockx2  = 500
```